# VB.NET Custom Lookupeditor/combobox

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Within my application i have some code that get on a few forms, and i was wondering if anyone could provide some suggestions on how to achieve this. 
I have 2 contact list (interfaces) that the application can use, and based on an setting it will determine to either use an internal or external list of contacts. I'm using a devexpress lookupedit, but the concept should be the similar for a combobox.

What i am doing is:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = classContactsFunctions.GetContactList()
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            With cbSupervisorID
                .Properties.DataSource = dt  ' Specify the data source to display in the dropdown.
                .Properties.DisplayMember = "FullName"  ' The field providing the editor's display text.
                .Properties.ValueMember = "InterfaceCode" ' The field matching the edit value.
            End With
            ' Add two columns to the dropdown.
            Dim coll As DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfoCollection = cbSupervisorID.Properties.Columns
            coll.Add(New DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("InterfaceCode", 0))
            coll.Add(New DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("Surname", 0))
            coll.Add(New DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("FirstName", 0))
            cbSupervisorID.Properties.Columns("InterfaceCode").Visible = False
            With cbSupervisorID
                .Properties.BestFitMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BestFitMode.BestFitResizePopup    ' Set column widths according to their contents and resize the popup, if required
                .Properties.SearchMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.SearchMode.AutoComplete            ' Enable auto completion search mode.
                .Properties.AutoSearchColumnIndex = 1                       ' Specify the column against which to perform the search.
            End With
        End If
```

What i would like to try achieve is create a custom class/item that i can drag onto my form and re-use it as often as i like without having to re-do all this code. Hopefully, a lookupedit that I can just drag onto my form and it will always populate as per the code.

Any suggestions or directions would be great

Answer (score 0):

Solution in end was move all that code into a class

```
    Shared Function SetupContactsLookupEditor(ByRef thelookup As LookUpEdit)
    Dim dt As DataTable = classContactsFunctions.GetContactList()
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        With thelookup
            .Properties.DataSource = dt  ' Specify the data source to display in the dropdown.
            .Properties.DisplayMember = "FullName"  ' The field providing the editor's display text.
            .Properties.ValueMember = "InterfaceCode" ' The field matching the edit value.
        End With

        'Add two columns to the dropdown.
        Dim coll As LookUpColumnInfoCollection = thelookup.Properties.Columns
        coll.Add(New LookUpColumnInfo("InterfaceCode", 0))
        coll.Add(New LookUpColumnInfo("Surname", 0))
        coll.Add(New LookUpColumnInfo("FirstName", 0))
        ' thelookup.Properties.Columns("InterfaceCode").Visible = False

        With thelookup
            .Properties.BestFitMode = BestFitMode.BestFitResizePopup          ' Set column widths according to their contents and resize the popup, if required
            .Properties.SearchMode = SearchMode.AutoComplete        ' Enable auto completion search mode.
            .Properties.AutoSearchColumnIndex = 1         ' Specify the column against which to perform the search.
        End With

    End If
    Return thelookup
End Function
```

and then when I need to set up the lookupedit i just call:

```
 cbReportedToContactCode = classContactsFunctions.SetupContactsLookupEditor(cbReportedToContactCode)
```